# PHP error reporting will not turn off

Tags: php, error-reporting, ini-set

Preface: I have already searched for previous answers to similar questions, tried to implement suggested solutions, and my problem has still not been resolved. Also, I do not need to be told to solve the problem causing the error message as I have deliberately caused an error to learn the ins and outs of changing the error reporting values in the php.ini file, directly and indirectly.

---

I have tried to turn off error reporting directly in the php.ini file by making display_errors=Off. Also, I have tried to switch it off indirectly using error_reporting(0); and ini_set('error_reporting',0);

I still cannot get error reporting to switch off. If someone could help me to identify why I cannot turn off error reporting, I would appreciate it.

Edit: I apologise for not being more specific. Can't believe I forgot to say: I am working with XAMPP offline.

---

Here is the code causing the error (a semicolon is missing after the echo)

```
<?php
echo $var = 'Dave'
$var = 'John';
?>
```

---

@Chris Rasco: I'm not entirely sure what information you would like from the phpinfo() page, but here's what seems to me (as a newbie) to be the most relevant:

Configure Command   cscript /nologo configure.js "--enable-snapshot-build" "--disable-isapi" "--enable-debug-pack" "--without-mssql" "--without-pdo-mssql" "--without-pi3web" "--with-pdo-oci=C:\php-sdk\oracle\instantclient10\sdk,shared" "--with-oci8=C:\php-sdk\oracle\instantclient10\sdk,shared" "--with-oci8-11g=C:\php-sdk\oracle\instantclient11\sdk,shared" "--enable-object-out-dir=../obj/" "--enable-com-dotnet=shared" "--with-mcrypt=static" "--disable-static-analyze" "--with-pgo"

Configuration File (php.ini) Path   C:\Windows

Loaded Configuration File   C:\xampp\php\php.ini

Scan this dir for additional .ini files (none)

Additional .ini files parsed    (none)

---

@Fred -ii-: yes, that is essentially what I am doing. I am trying to see how to change how changing various parts of the php.ini file affects the output in the browser.

---

Finally! I've fixed the problem. Thanks, guys! I can't believe I made the stupid error of not restarting Apache after editing the php.ini file.

Comment: What is out the output of phpinfo(); telling you about the current config and any additional config files that are loaded?

Comment: Keep in mind there is error_reporting and display_errors. Is your intent to keep the users from seeing errors? What's the value of display_errors on your phpinfo(); output?

Answer (score 1):

Could you share the error message? I'd be curious to see if it's a `E_FATAL` error.

Missing a `;` would produce a `E_FATAL` error.
You can't suppress a fatal error because it is a compiling error.

In other words: In that case your php script cannot compile and has to terminate.

Comment: This is the error:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' in C:\xampp\htdocs\thenewbostonphptutorials\index.php on line 2

Comment: @Bas is right - a parse error is thrown by the internal workings of Apache's `mod_php` compiler and happens before the file is even executed, so any of the "indirect" methods like `ini_set()` or `error_reporting()` will have no effect. You'll have to concentrate on the settings in `php.ini` - look at both `display_errors` and `error_reporting` for the settings, and **don't forget to restart Apache after making any changes!**

Answer (score 0):

search below line in php.ini file in your xamp

```
;error_reporting=E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT & ~E_NOTICE
```

then once you found above line then remove `;` from line.
it will switch off your error.